# Cloud storage bitbucket pipeline ignores directories

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage, continuous-deployment, bitbucket-pipelines

I have below pipeline

```
image: node:10.15.3

pipelines:
  default:
      - step:
          name: Installing
          caches:
            - node
          script:
            - rm -rf package-lock.json
            - rm -rf node_modules
            - npm install
      - step:
          name: Build
          script:
            - npm install --production
          artifacts:
            - build/**
      - step:
          name: Deploying
          script:
          - pipe: atlassian/google-cloud-storage-deploy:0.4.5
            variables:
              KEY_FILE: $KEY_FILE
              PROJECT: $PROJECT
              BUCKET: 'bucketname'
              SOURCE: 'build'
              CACHE_CONTROL: 'max-age=30'
              ACL: 'public-read'
```

The expected behavior is to deploy everything inside the build folder, but it uploads the build folder itself so in my storage, there is a build folder then everything inside this...

I have tried

> 'build/**' it picks only files and ignore directories
>
> 'buiid/' it behave same as 'build' picks build directory along with  everything inside it directories and folders
>
> 'build/*' it picks only files and ignore directories

How can I everything inside build folder , files and diectories..

Thanks

Comment: Could you please add more details? I don't get at all what do you mean with this:

`The expected behavior is to deploy everything inside the build folder, but it uploads the build folder itself so in my storage, there is a build folder then everything inside this...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, it's inside pipeline, there was only copy command I removed the pipeline and wriiiten explicitly with -r to copy the folder recursively